# TabBar is not showing TabBar Item title Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

> i am try to add title to my tab bar items, but it is not showing don't know why

```
fileprivate func appenedVC(for rootViewController: UIViewController,tabBarTitle: String, image: UIImage) -> UIViewController {

    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    navController.tabBarItem.title = title
    navController.tabBarItem.image = image
    rootViewController.navigationItem.title = title
    navController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    return navController
}
```

> here is viewDidload where i am using this method

```
abBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.5690457821, blue: 0.5746168494, alpha: 1)
    tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = .black


    viewControllers = [
        appenedVC(for: CategoryVC(), tabBarTitle: "Category", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "categoryFilled")),
        appenedVC(for: FeedbackVC(), tabBarTitle: "Feedback", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "feedbackIFilled"))
    ]
```

> Output

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in your view controller - viewDidLoad()

```
self.title = “title“
self.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: “tabImage“)
self.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: “tabSelected”)
```

You can do that through storyboard as well. Select the Tab bar item in your navigation controller and go to attribute inspector and enter the title.

[image]

Comment: This app is  Programmatically implemented

Comment: May be issue with title color. Try with this

UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .normal)

Comment: If solution works for you, would you please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Setup tabBarItem for embedded controller in navigation controller.

```swift
  fileprivate func appenedVC(for rootViewController: UIViewController, tabBarTitle: String, image: UIImage) -> UIViewController {
    rootViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: title, image: image, selectedImage: image)
    rootViewController.title = tabBarTitle
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    navController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    return navController
  }
```